# Numpy deep copy still altering original array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, deep-copy

As I understand it, a deep copy of an ndarray should create a second iteration of the ndarray so that changing either array will not affect the contents of the other. However, in the following code, my original ndarray is changed:

```
print(data[3])   #[array([[0.00000000e+00, 3.29530000e+04],
   #[4.00066376e-04, 3.29530000e+04],
   #[8.00132751e-04, 3.29530000e+04],
   #...,
   #[1.28784461e+03, 3.47140000e+04],
   #[1.28784621e+03, 3.57750000e+04],
   #[1.28785381e+03, 1.92450000e+04]]),
   #'CH4.VDC1']

new = np.empty_like(data)
new[:] = data
new[3][0][:,1] = 4/16421 * (data[3][0][:,1] - 33563)

print(data[3])  #[array([[ 0.00000000e+00, -1.48590220e-01],
   #[ 4.00066376e-04, -1.48590220e-01],
   #[ 8.00132751e-04, -1.48590220e-01],
   #...,
   #[ 1.28784461e+03,  2.80372694e-01],
   #[ 1.28784621e+03,  5.38822240e-01],
   #[ 1.28785381e+03, -3.48772913e+00]]),
   #'CH4.VDC1']
```

The array is a mixed type (5,2) array with a (largenumber,2) subarray inside. I am only trying to change the subarray but I am wondering if the deep copy extends to that subarray as well. I have run

```
np.shares_memory(new, data) #false

np.might_share_memory(new,data) #false
```

It might also be important to note that I am running this in a jupyter notebook. Although I can't imagine why it would change anything. You can recreate data with:

```
np.array([[[[0.00000000e+00, 2.82540000e+04],
[4.00066376e-04, 2.82530000e+04],
[8.00132751e-04, 2.82520000e+04],
[1.28784461e+03, 4.61170000e+04],
[1.28784621e+03, 3.38280000e+04],
[1.28785381e+03, 3.38230000e+04]],
'CH1.Bx'],
[[[0.00000000e+00, 2.00400000e+04],
[4.00066376e-04, 2.00400000e+04],
[8.00132751e-04, 2.00410000e+04],
[1.28784461e+03, 1.81600000e+04],
[1.28784621e+03, 1.80830000e+04],
[1.28785381e+03, 4.80200000e+03]],
'CH2.By'],
[array([[0.00000000e+00, 3.82520000e+04],
[4.00066376e-04, 3.82510000e+04],
[8.00132751e-04, 3.82510000e+04],
[1.28784461e+03, 3.42810000e+04],
[1.28784621e+03, 3.42820000e+04],
[1.28785381e+03, 3.40380000e+04]]),
'CH3.Bz'],
[[[ 0.00000000e+00, -1.48590220e-01],
[ 4.00066376e-04, -1.48590220e-01],
[ 8.00132751e-04, -1.48590220e-01],
[ 1.28784461e+03,  2.80372694e-01],
[ 1.28784621e+03,  5.38822240e-01],
[ 1.28785381e+03, -3.48772913e+00]],
'CH4.VDC1'],
[[[0.00000000e+00, 3.26760000e+04],
[4.00066376e-04, 3.26760000e+04],
[8.00132751e-04, 3.26750000e+04],
[1.28784981e+03, 3.40450000e+04],
[1.28785061e+03, 3.40420000e+04],
[1.28785141e+03, 3.40390000e+04]],
'CH5.VDC2']], dtype=object)`
```

Comment: Can you share the entire `data` so as to reproduce this?

Comment: Your object dtype array contains references to objects elsewhere in memory.  The level of copying that works for ordinary numeric arrays does not make copies of those objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That doesn't look like an array you're starting with there. It's not clear what `data` is, but `data[3]` is a 2-element list containing an array and a string, and judging by that, `data` is probably another list, or possibly an object-dtype array.

Your attempt at a deep copy:

```
new = np.empty_like(data)
new[:] = data
```

is not a deep copy. It would be a copy for most normal arrays (deep/shallow are equivalent for most arrays), but not a deep copy for a list, and not a deep copy for an object-dtype array. It will create a new object-dtype array and fill it with references to the same objects referenced by the cells of `data`.

You should probably pick a better way to organize your data. This data structure is not an effective way to work with NumPy, and it will cause more problems than just this. That said, if you want to deep copy it, `copy.deepcopy` is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [copy's deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy), [:] does not do a deepcopy:

```
In [11]: a = [[1], 2]

In [12]: b = a[:]

In [13]: from copy import deepcopy
    ...: c = deepcopy(a)

In [14]: b[0].append(3)

In [15]: a
Out[15]: [[1, 3], 2]

In [16]: c
Out[16]: [[1], 2]
```

Comment: But [in the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html), it implies that np.copy is a deep copy. So would I really need to step out of numpy to do this?

Comment: @Bob In contrast to python lists, `[:]` does not copy an array. An you do not use `np.copy` anywhere in your code. `np.copy` is a copy, though I do not think it will deep copy arbitrary objects, but it should work as expected for numerical values.

Comment: @BobSherwin I don't see that in the link, I just tested it, and it's not a deep copy.

Comment: I see. So I guess it must be a shallow copy. [This tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_copies_and_views.htm) seems to have it wrong then.

@jan [:] does not copy but the initial creation should right?

Comment: @BobSherwin I think it will if it's a single dtype array (a "proper" numpy array), if it's an array of objects (even numpy objects) it's not going to deep copy. This is the OP's situtation (numpy arrays within a numpy array)